# How do I get the host name from a URL in Perl using regex?

Tags: regex, perl, url, host

so what I want to do is remove everything after and including the first "/" to appear after a "."
so: http://linux.pacific.net.au/primary.xml.gz
would become: http://linux.pacific.net.au

How do I do this using regex? The system I'm running on can't use URI tool.

Comment: I assume you have tried something and couldn't do it. Show us your work first.

Comment: Just because you can't use a Perl module doesn't mean that you can't look inside it to see what it does and how it does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use [`URI::Split`](https://www.metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aSplit) which will separate a standard URL into its constuent parts for you and rejoin them. You want the first two parts - the *scheme* and the *host*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI::Split qw/ uri_split uri_join /;

my $scheme_host = do {
  my (@parts) = uri_split 'http://linux.pacific.net.au/primary.xml.gz';
  uri_join @parts[0,1];
};

print $scheme_host;
```

**output**

```
http://linux.pacific.net.au
```

---

**Update**

If your comment *The system I'm running on can't use URI tool* means you can't install modules, then here is a regular expression solution.

You say you want to *remove everything after and including the first "/" to appear after a "."*, so `/^.*?\./` finds the first dot, and `m|[^/]+|` finds everything after it up tot he next slash.

The output is identical to that of the preceding code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = 'http://linux.pacific.net.au/primary.xml.gz';

my ($scheme_host) = $url =~ m|^( .*?\. [^/]+ )|x;

print $scheme_host;
```

Comment: I have a feeling it is a assignment question and s/he needs to build the regex...

Comment: @Hameed: Hmm maybe. I've also just realised that *The system I'm running on can't use URI tool* probably means the URI module

Answer (score 6):

```
$url = 'http://linux.pacific.net.au/primary.xml.gz';
($domain) = $url =~ m!(https?://[^:/]+)!;
print $domain;
```

output:

```
http://linux.pacific.net.au
```

and this is the official regular expression can be used to decode a URI:

```
  my($scheme, $authority, $path, $query, $fragment) =
  $uri =~ m|(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?|;
```

Answer (score 4):

> The system I'm running on can't use URI tool.

I really recommend doing whatever you can to fix that problem first. If you're not able to use CPAN modules then you'll be missing out on a lot of the power of Perl and your Perl programming life will be far more frustrating than it needs to be.